# refresh/update highcharts bar chart through external button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I tried to reload/update highcharts bar chart data from the table(https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed) through the external button.

In my code, when click reload button it is working only once. If I change data and again click reload button it still doesn't working.

```html
$(function () {
      
      $('#containerbarchart').highcharts({
          data: {
              table: document.getElementById('datatable')
          },
          chart: {
              type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
          },
          yAxis: {
              allowDecimals: false,
              title: {
                  text: 'Units'
              }
          },
          tooltip: {
              formatter: function() {
                  return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                      this.y +' '+ this.x;
              }
          },
          
         
          series : [{ id: 'series1' }, { id: 'series2' },{ id: 'series3' }]
      });
        $("#barchart").click(function() {
      
      $("#td1").html(11);
      $("#td2").html(20);
      $("#td3").html(15);
          
          
          var complete = function(options) {
              var chart = $('#containerbarchart').highcharts();
        var options = chart.options;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
              var chart = $('#containerbarchart').highcharts();
              var series1 = chart.get('series1');
              var series2 = chart.get('series2');
              var series3 = chart.get('series3');
              
              
              series1.setData(options.series[0].data, false);
              series2.setData(options.series[1].data, false);
              series3.setData(options.series[2].data, false);
              
              
              chart.redraw();
          };
          
         
          Highcharts.data({
              table : document.getElementById('datatable'),
              complete : complete
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Can we have the HTML please?

Comment: Provide us with a fully working example.